# How to write QFile in Blackberry 10 device?

Tags: blackberry-10, qfile

I am new in Blackberry 10, I want to create file in device document.

Does anyone knows how to do same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access device's Documents folder by using `"/accounts/1000/shared/documents"` path. You need `access_shared` permission to access the shared folders. You can find more information about BB10 file system [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/data_access/file_system.html).

Following is sample code which shows how to write file using QFile.

```
QFile textfile("/accounts/1000/shared/documents/newfile.txt");
textfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream out(&textfile);
out << "This is a text file\n";
textfile.close();
```